# how to call nco package into jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter, netcdf, nco

I want to work with algebraic operation on netcdf files. I saw that the package nco does that.  I have installed the package though conda but when i call it in jupyter notebook, it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NCO'"

In the documentation of the package i did not find anything about working with jupyter notebook environment.

I am working whit python version 3.5. Windows 10 (64b)

My assumption is that maybe this package was not developed to be run through jupyter. any hint?

Comment: please, if you are going to score with minus, at least tell me what is wrong with this question.

Comment: I tried installing [pynco](https://github.com/nco/pynco) into my windows anaconda environment. I am not sure if this is the one you are using. But it does say that Windows hasn't been properly tested. And python>=3.6 is a requirement. On my system it did install `nco` command line tools, which was kind of neat. The package loaded in jupyter but there were a few weird things and not all of the demo code worked. Have you tried running at the python command line instead of jupyter?

Comment: thanks @Robert Davy.  I have to use jupyter because is the common interface for my interdisciplinary team.                     
     Just to double check:  you installed pynci package and you called out as  `import pynco` in Jupyter?. Thanks a lot for your feedback :)

Comment: As per the documentation I used `conda install pynco`. However, the first command to load the package is `from nco import Nco`. See if that works and then try the other commands in the doc page.